# how to check if JSON column contains a INT value in POSTGRESQL (SQLALCHEMY)

Tags: python, json, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have this table :

```
class Users(base):
    # table setting
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = Column('id', BIGINT, primary_key=True)
    firstname = Column('firstname', VARCHAR(64))
    blocked = Column('blocked', JSON, default=[])  # [blocked_id]
```

I have added some rows into that table:

```
await session.execute(
    insert(Users).values(firstname='user_1', blocked=[1, 2, 3])
)
await session.execute(
    insert(Users).values(firstname='user_2', blocked=[2, 3, 4])
)
await session.execute(
    insert(Users).values(firstname='user_3', blocked=[3, 4, 5])
)
await session.commit()
```

And I need to get the first user who has value `1` in column `blocked`

(in this scenario is the first user that I added into that table)

here is how I'm trying to do it :

```
request = await session.execute(
                select(Users.firstname) \
                .where(Users.blocked.contains(1)) \
                .order_by(Users.id) \
                .limit(1) 
        )
result = request.fetchone()
```

can you please help?

Answer (score 0):

From [Docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/postgresql.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.JSONB)

> The JSONB type includes all operations provided by JSON, including the same behaviors for indexing operations. It also adds additional operators specific to JSONB, including Comparator.has_key(), Comparator.has_all(), Comparator.has_any(), Comparator.contains(), and Comparator.contained_by().

So in order to use the `contains()` method, you either need to declare your column as a JSONB type, or you can also cast it first to JSONB type.

```py
class Users(base):
    ...
    blocked = Column('blocked', JSONB, default=[])  # [blocked_id]
```

**FYI also from the docs** :

> Like the JSON type, the JSONB type does not detect in-place changes when used with the ORM, unless the sqlalchemy.ext.mutable extension is used.

So if you change this field value and commit. It is not sure that an UPDATE statement will be emitted, and you should call the `update()` method explicitly